# How to clear preg_match_all from empty array values

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I am using preg_match_all to build  the array for shortcodes 
and it works fine but it also returns arrays with empty values 
see here please

https://eval.in/141437

Using this match witch I am sure is casuing the extra empty arrays

```
#\[link(.*?)link\=\"(.*?)\"(.*?)text\=\"(.*?)\"\]#e
```

How can I clear those. 
I tried array_filter but it did not work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`()` represent a capture group and will be represented in the `$matches` array even if it is empty.

Either get rid of the `()` around the groups that are returning empty like `(.*?)` to make it just `.*?` (because presumably you don't want those returned) or tell the engine not to capture that with `(?:` like `(?:.*?)`.

```
#\[link.*?link\=\"(.*?)\".*?text\=\"(.*?)\"\]#e
```

Or if you do want those returned when they are not empty, then use `+` instead of `*`:

```
#\[link(.+?)link\=\"(.*?)\"(.+?)text\=\"(.*?)\"\]#e
```

Comment: Nailed it! Both options work. Thank you. Must wait few min to accept.

Comment: OK, edited right as you accepted to include if you wanted those groups when not empty.

Comment: Thank you again. What I am trying to say with that expression is , capture the string inside "" and dont pay attention what is in between the tags like   link---ANYTHING--text. Your explanation now makes sense since I was using () and captured everything

Answer (score 0):

The array_filter() function should work if you use it like this:

```
$matches = array_filter($matches, function($item) { return trim($item[0]) && true; });
```

AbraCadaver's answer is the best way to go.